# What are the chart type code for clustered chart?

Tags: qtp

Can someone tell me the code used for clustered chart?
For eg:objChart.ChartType = -4100 is for bar chart

Can someone please list out the codes used for different kinds of charts in excel used in QTP?

Thanks in advance... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see a list of Excel's [chart types here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838409.aspx).

According to this `-4100` is `xl3DColumn` (3D Column)